# Romanian character 'ă' equals 'a' in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, diacritics

I am working on a SQL Server database that stores Romanian words. Romanian words may contain various special characters (diacritics), like 'ă', 'ș', 'ț', 'î' or 'â'. I have items with and without diacritics. I noticed that if a user searches for something that contains 'a', it also returns results that do not contain 'a', but 'ă'.

Is there a way to prevent 'ă' being equated to 'a'?

My database uses SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS collation.

Comment: What is the data type of the column in the database?  What is the data type of the variable you are trying to compare to?

Comment: The column and the variable are both varchar.

Comment: *"The column and the variable are both varchar."* I see my crystal ball is working today then. :)

Comment: @Larnu yes it does :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not that `a` equals `ă`, persay, it's that the string `'ă'` can't be represented correctly in a `varchar` with the collation you are using; thus `'ă'` is instead represented as `'a'` (and that is unsurprising equal to `'a'`). As such `'ă'` *does* equal `'a'` (using the collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) as the former value changes before the comparison is attempted. You need to use an `nvarchar`:

```sql
SELECT CASE N'ă' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS WHEN 'a' THEN 1 END;
```

This returns `NULL` as the boolean expression is not true.

Comment: Could you explain briefly why this does not happen with other characters, like 'â' or 'ș'?

Comment: Because `'â'` *can* be represented in the code page you are using, and `'ș'` is an unrecognised character in the code page and so is lost (and so represented by `'?'`), @CristisS .

Comment: You are right. Totally forgot about this. Thanks again!

Comment: To give my two cents to this, and in a very simplistic way: "_AS" at the end of the collation name means "accent sensitive", that means ă and a are treated as different letters (in opposite to "_AI", which means "accent insensitive"). And to be a smartass: CI means "case insensitive", which treats A and a as the same. CS (case sensitive) would treat them as different.

Comment: That isn't the problem here, @MichaelTobisch . The problem isn't the collation's sensitivity, the OP *is* using an accent sensitive collation, it is that lack of representation of the characters in the code page used by `varchar` in the collation the OP is trying to compare in.